# What do you call this place where various goods are sold?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, image-identification

What do you call the establishment where you buy things, like on the picture?

[image: picture of a store will good stocked on shelves behind a counter with a clerk]

Should I call it shop, store or market? I am in total confusion. I am asking for a generic term for a place where they sell things (maybe non-edible), not just a place where only food and drinks are sold.

Answer (score 5):

In American English, it would usually be called a convenience store.

> A [convenience store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenience_store) is a small retail business that stocks a range of everyday items such as groceries, snack foods, confectionery, soft drinks, tobacco products, over-the-counter drugs, toiletries, newspapers, and magazines.

Comment: What is the generic term for such business, small or big and selling different things (say, clothing or toys)?

Comment: For instance, I heard about "sex-shop" but what about "sex-store"? What about other types of goods?

Comment: I would say that in the US, generally speaking, you are more likely to use/hear _store_. But other words exist, like _shop_ and _boutique_. I feel like those are used for specialty stores. Usually, they are called "sex shops" as far as I know (although there are some results online for "sex store"). I can't really think of any other examples like that one. "Coffee shop" is a good one to know.

Comment: @Anixx Asking for lists is off-topic. However, [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/types-of-shop) has a useful list of shop types. Note that some terms, such as *victualler*, are archaic.

Comment: @Mick shop types or store types? What is the generic term?

Comment: @Anixx In the UK, small establishments are called *shops*, and large ones are called *stores*. Asian establishments are sometimes called *emporia* (singular *emporium*), since that term is still used in the subcontinent. A generic term would be "retail outlet".

Comment: @Mick I do not think it is a generic term. Suppose you are creating a computer game. Would you call it there "build a retail outlet in the town" or "visit a retail outlet to buy stuff"? Also, a retail outlet can be a kiosk or even a selling machine.

Comment: @Anixx It's the most generic term that I can think of.

Comment: @Mick by the way, by large ones you mean supermarkets?

Comment: @Anixx A store is a large shop. It is often prefixed to indicate what is being sold, e.g. *furniture store*, *hardware store*. A *supermarket* is a large store that usually sells groceries and other household products. We also have *super-stores*, *hyper-markets*, *shopping-malls*, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In British English, this would be a shop; an establishment where goods are sold retail. Specifically, it looks like a "corner shop", so called because they are often sited on street corners in residential areas. If you search for images of "corner shop" on Google you will get a lot more examples.

A "store" is the American English equivalent of "shop".

A "market" is a collection of independent stalls within a defined area. In some cases this is within a large open indoor space, and in others it is out of doors. Each stallholder rents a few square yards/meters from the owner of the space, and can then put up tables and awnings and display their goods. The main distinction between "shop" and "stall" is that a shop is permanent whereas a stall is temporary. Again, if you google for images of "market" you will get some good examples.

Note that "supermarket" is not the same as a "market". A supermarket is just a very large shop offering a wide variety of goods. It is not a "market" in the sense described above.

Answer (score 1):

corner store, convenience store, if it also sold newspapers it would be a newsagent, if it sold hardware as well it would be a general store, if it sold booze it would an off licence - and if it was in Royston Vassey it would be a local shop for local people!

Comment: 'shops' provide service (workshop, bodyshop etc) but may also sell thier wares, A store sells items and also carry stock or inventory( thats where the 'store' comes in - they also store stuff. Amarket denotes sale of items by multiple vendors. A shop may also be differentiated from store by its reduced inventory.. You would,nt expect a local shop to carry a large range and stock - where a store would.

Comment: Maybe some regional differences.  In the US, the term would be "news stand" rather than "newsagent" (which, if that term was used at all, people would assume referred to a broker who manages subscriptions to news stands).  :-)